# Watching multiple scratch directories on S3 in TensorBoard

Tags: amazon-s3, tensorboard

I have two experiment scratch directories on s3, let's say `s3://my-bucket/dir1` and `s3://my-bucket/dir2`, which I want to visualize at the same time with TensorBoard. I tried doing `tensorboard --lodgir s3://my-bucket/dir1,s3://my-bucket/dir2`, and I see the "No dashboards are active for the current data set." message. I confirmed that I'm able to see the graphs with both `tensorboard s3://my-bucket/dir1`, and `tensorboard s3://my-bucket/dir2`. I also confirmed that TensorBoard works as expected if I organize the two directories under `s3://my-bucket/dirs`, and do `tensorboard --logdir s3://my-bucket/dirs`. Our ML infrastructure is rather complicated, so I'd like to avoid just modifying the code to store artifacts in this way if I can. Is this a bug to TensorBoard, or am I missing something here?

The TensorBoard version is 2.11.2